# How to write Local Language in a textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

i want to write any text in my local language (Spanish or Bengali) in a particular textBox

Please tell me how can i do that ?

Thank`s.

Comment: It's not a question. It's like how can I drink water

Comment: The user can type into a TextBox in any language they want. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: You natively can (pardon the pun). If you manage to type in your language in Notepad, then you can also type in your language in a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look up "WPF internationalization".  There are lots of resources, including excellent Microsoft documentation.

Here's a good place to start:

[Internationalization in .Net and WPF](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/internationalization-in-net-and-wpf-presentation-foundation)

The key is:

- Defining separate resources for each language
- Defining your UI to look up the per-language resource (instead of using hard-coded strings)

PS:

As far as text *INPUT* - the user can enter anything he wants; her PC locale can default to any language available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your keyboard language accordingly or just copy and paste from the google translate services.